# Button not redirecting

Tags: laravel

i have an  order button  that is supposed to redirect the user to the cart page with the items ordered

```
<p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{route('addCart',$food->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center" role="button" > Order this</a> </p>
```

This is the route on web.php

```
Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', 'FoodsController@addToCart')->name('addCart');
```

This is the function addToCart

```
public function addToCart($id){
        $food = Food::find($id);   

        if(!$food) {

            abort(404);

        }

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {

            $cart = [
                    $id => [
                        // "productId" => $food->id,
                        "name" => $food->food_item,
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "price" => $food->price,

                    ]
            ];


            session()->put('cart', $cart);


            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }

        // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
        if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

        }

        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart[$id] = [
            // "productId" => $food->id,
            "name" => $food->food_item,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $food->price,

        ];


        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }
```

But when i click the button it doesn't redirect to the cart page it keeps loading to the same spot 
i did

```
 dd($food);
```

on the fuction and it outputs right results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an order button that is supposed to redirect the user to the cart page with the items ordered

What you are doing when you use `return redirect()->back()->with...` is you are redirecting the user *back* to the page they came from, in this case the page where your `Order this` button is.

So the logic currently is:

1. On product page
2. User clicks `Order this` button
3. The product is either added to the cart, or incremented
4. The user is then redirected back to the previous page

If you want the user to be redirected to another page when clicking the `Order this` button, you will need to redirect the user to either another page, or another route, like so

```
return redirect()->route('View Cart')->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
```

or like this:

```
return redirect('/view-cart')->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
```

Which should result in the following flow:

1. On product page
2. User clicks `Order this` button
3. The product is either added to the cart, or incremented
4. The user is then redirected **to the view cart page**

I don't know what routes you have, so the above is an approximation.