# Cart does not display items laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an order **button** that is supposed to redirect the user to the cart page with the items ordered

```
<p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{route('addCart',$food->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center" role="button" > Order this</a> </p>
```

This is the **Route** on web.php

```
Route::get('add-to-cart/{id}', 'FoodsController@addToCart')->name('addCart');
```

This is the function **addToCart**

```
public function addToCart($id){
        $food = Food::find($id);   

        if(!$food) {

            abort(404);

        }

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {

            $cart = [
                    $id => [
                        // "productId" => $food->id,
                        "name" => $food->food_item,
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "price" => $food->price,

                    ]
            ];


            session()->put('cart', $cart);


            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }

        // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
        if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

        }

        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart[$id] = [
            // "productId" => $food->id,
            "name" => $food->food_item,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $food->price,

        ];


        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }
```

But when I click the button it doesn't redirect to the cart page, it keeps loading to the same spot.

I tried dumping the variable using `dd($food);` on the addToCart fuction and it outputs right results

Comment: i would make a route just to view the cart and redirect there if that's what you want, and then call `redirect('/cart');` at the end of the controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button not redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678924/button-not-redirecting)

Comment: You're redirecting the user "back", not to the cart. What happens if you replace " back()" with "route(<cart_route_name>)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's exactly what "redirect()->back()" is supposed to do, send you back to the page you come from.

You should use:

```
redirect('cartRouteName')->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
```

Replacing 'cartRouteName' with the actual named route you want to redirect the user to.

Please see here for more info on redirects to named routes in Laravel:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects